# Sharing Dropbox Folders with Secondary Email adresses

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I want to share a dropbox folder with a bunch of people at my university. I only have their university email adresses. I suspect most of them already have a private dropbox account associated with their personal email adresses, and they probably don't want to create a seperate account. Can I share a dropbox folder with them in such a way that they will be able to add it to their private accounts, without me having to ask for their private email adresses?

If I share it with their uni adresses, will they get the option to add it to a different account (their personal accounts)? Will sharing a link allow them to use it like any other shared folder (not only view but also add and modify)? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can invite your friends, but they have to make a separate account for each email they own.

This also means that unless your university mates are not clever, they would already have upgraded their own dropbox by inviting their own 2nd email address, and you're out of people to invite.